# EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION Error for find contours function

Tags: java, video-processing, javacv

I am using cvFindContours to find the contours of edge detected frames. First I use cvCanny to get the edges frame from actual frame. Then I am trying to find the contours.Here is my code structure

//used cvcanny to get cur and next frames

```
CvMemStorage curstorage=CvMemStorage.create();
CvMemStorage nextstorage=CvMemStorage.create();

CvSeq cursquares = new CvContour();
CvSeq nextsquares = new CvContour();

cvFindContours(cur, curstorage, cursquares, Loader.sizeof(CvContour.class),CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

cvFindContours(next, nextstorage, nextsquares, Loader.sizeof(CvContour.class),CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
```

When I run the code I get Access Violation Exception.Here is the exception details.

> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>
> EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000062e3c320, pid=9184, tid=6236
>
> JRE version: 7.0_17-b02
>    Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.7-b01 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
>    Problematic frame:
>    C  [msvcr100.dll+0x3c320]  memset+0x80
>
> Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows

I am not sure where I am going wrong as I have just started using javacv.Any suggestions regarding this will be helpful.Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably do not reference your `CvMemStorage` instances after the `cvFindContours` calls, only the `CvSeq`'s. The storage might be evaluated as not referenced and thus GCed, while you still need to use CvSeq, which depends on the storage. This will cause EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION at the first usage of CvSeq after the GC happens.

Try to add:

```
curstorage.release();
nextstorage.release();
```

after you quit using CvSeq. It has two advantages: it proactively releases native memory without waiting to GC and it prevents the GC from releasing storages too early. See my question here: [JavaCV native object deallocation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15896044/952135).